# i can't access phpmyadmin on other computer locally

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, localserver

i hope someone can help me
i'm using XAMPP server i configured it and it was working perfectly just a week ago, now i didn't change anything but i can't access phpmyadmin from my other laptop on the same network.
-> i have changed `httpd.conig` made it listen to a specific ip adress (`Listen 127.1.1.2:80`).
-> i also changed `httpd.campp.config` so tjis part looks like this :

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
```

when i enter the ipv4 of my main laptop on the other laptop it works but when  i try to enter the ip adress `127.1.1.2 /phpmyadmin` it doesn't work

Comment: 127.1.1.2 is a loopback address just like 127.0.0.1. It will always resolve to the same computer that's sending the request, not to your second one. This applies to all addresses in the CIDR range 127.0.0.0/8.

Comment: @CherryDT ty i'll try using another ip adress

Comment: so after changing the IP @ from 127.1.1.2 to something else, nothing works unless it's the ipv4 of my main pc and i can't be using that because it varies. 
apach doesn't even start and shows this message: 
8:31:59 PM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
8:31:59 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:31:59 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

Comment: Well that's how it works though. You have to use an IP that's accessible from your other computer, i.e. your LAN IP. If it varies, either don't let it vary in the first place (assign a static IP) or use a hostname instead, provided that your router offers NetBIOS hostname resolution in your internal network (most do).

Comment: And the error means you now have two services listening on the same IP+port combination.

Comment: @CherryDT i solved the error, thank yo uso much for your time... i'll try to find a way to fix the ip adress of the main pc. i appreciate ur answers ty so much